# Yii2 How to use two different Models in one GridView

Tags: gridview, controller, grid, action, yii2

I have some data in tow different Model one in Job (Department, Company...) and Employee (EmpName, EmpAge, EmpPosition...)

How can I use both of the models inside one gridview in order to have a table like (EmpName, EmpPosition, Company, Department....)

I know How to create gridview from one Model

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'EmpName',
             'EmpPosition',   ...........     ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined a relation in your Employee model to get a reference to your Job model, it can be done with

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'EmpName',
            'EmpPosition',
            [
                'name' => 'Company',
                'value' => '$data->Job->Company',
            ],   
            ...........     ],
]); ?>
```

**Employee model**

```
::
function getJob() {
    /*
     * Assumptions:
     * - foreign key to job in employee table is named job_id
     * - primary key in job table is named id
     */
    return this->hasOne(Job::classname(), ['id' => 'job_id']);
}
::
```

See [Yii2 Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/) for additional information

Comment: Oh ok I see, but no I didn't defined relation in Employee model, how can I do it please ? thx

Comment: @Test404 See Employee model in answer.

Answer (score 1):

for me it doesn't work with this:

```
[

'name' => 'Company',
'value' => '$data->Job->Company',
],
```

**it worked correctly with** :

```
[

'label' => 'Company',
'value' => function ($data){ return $data->Job->Company; },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 GridView DataColumn supports dot notation for model relations

```
[
  'name' => 'Company',
  'value' => 'job.Company',
],
```

It's shorter in syntax and avoids exception when `$data->Job = null`.